# Invalid commands for child process in background in C

Tags: c, process, fork, parent, execvp

I have the following code in C:

```
        if ((childpid = fork()) == 0) {
            if (execvp(argv[0], argv) < 0) {
                //execute failed
                exit(1);
            }
        } else if (childpid < 0) {
            //fork failed
        } else {
            //if execvp failed don't do anything here
            //else do something
        }
```

What I want is:

I enter a command.

If it is not executable it should not do anything but wait for my next entered command.

If it is executable it should do some things in the parent process.

If I enter e.g. `sleep 1m` it should execute it in my child process, do things in the parent process and should be still able to execute more jobs (this works fine). But when I execute something like `abcdef` (invalid command) it does the stuff in my parent process anyway.

Can someone tell me how the code should look like?

I also tried the following:

```
void signalHandler(int signal)
{
    if (signal==SIGCHLD) {
        printf("Child ended\n");
        wait(NULL);
    }
}
//in main
signal(SIGCHLD,signalHandler);
//...
    if ((childpid = fork()) == 0) {
        if (execvp(t_argv[0], t_argv) < 0) {
            kill(getppid(),SIGCHLD);
        }
    }
```

Is this correct?
This way I get an error afterwards (when it's finished).

```
waitpid(childpid, &status, WNOHANG)
```

tells me it finished with an error (-1).

Comment: Unless you have some [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) between the parent and the child, there's really no way to notify the parent about e.g. `execvp` failing in the child.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Is there a way to reorganize my code so I can do what I want to have? Maybe killing the child after execvp failed?

Comment: By calling `exit` you are already "killing" the child. You *could* use e.g. [`waitpid`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html) with the `WNOHANG` option after a small timeout to see if the child process has exited, and check the child process exit code, and hope that the program you execute in the child doesn't use the same exit code. This will however be a very non-deterministic solution, as the timeout needs to be long enough for the child to actually run, and also because the exit code might be used by the program you execute and is not unique.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use a pair of anonymous pipes, where the child process writes in the write-end of the pipe any status it needs to pass on to the parent. Then in the parent you check the read-end of the pipe, if you don't receive anything before the child-process exits then everything was okay and the child process successfully executed the program.

If the parent does receive anything before the child process exits, then it means that the `exec` call failed.

Comment: Can you give me a code example for this please? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Monkey Search for *pipes fork* and you should get thousands of examples of using pipes for parent-child communication, mostly as a way of replacing either `stdin` or `stdout`, but it should give you enough information to know what functions to use, and then just read the manual pages for those functions.

Comment: I looked for some examples. Could it be that it works the same way as the SIGCHLD method?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to terminate abnormally with a signal (for example, `SIGUSR1`) and check for that in the parent. This assumes that whatever program you execute in the child never terminates with `SIGUSR1` - a reasonable assumption in most cases, I'd say. The parent can then check the termination status of the child.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    pid_t childpid;

        if ((childpid = fork()) == 0) {
            if (execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]) < 0) {
                raise(SIGUSR1);
            }
        } else if (childpid < 0) {
            perror("fork()");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else {
            int term_status;
            if (wait(&term_status) < 0) {
                perror("wait()");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            if (WIFSIGNALED(term_status) && WTERMSIG(term_status) == SIGUSR1) {
                printf("execvp failed\n");
            } else {
                printf("success\n");
            }
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Side note: you probably want `execvp(argv[1], &argv[1])`, because `execvp(argv[0], argv)` will execute this same program over and over.

Again, this works as long as the process executed by `execvp(2)` never terminates with `SIGUSR1`. Notice that if the process executed by `execvp(2)` terminates with `SIGSEGV` or other abnormal termination condition, it is still seen as success by the parent.

Comment: This works fine, thanks. But the problem is that I have to wait for the process till the parent is executed (e.g. sleep 1m). The only way would be to shorten the wait time, right?

Comment: @Monkey You could catch the `SIGCHLD` signal in the parent, it will be raised when a child process has stopped or terminated. The call `wait` in the signal handler. However, this is also non-deterministic, what if the `execvp` call succeeds but the child process is terminated by the user sending a `SIGUSR1` signal to the child process?

Comment: @Monkey I don't understand. Wait for which process?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I tried it. You can see it in my original post.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves If I enter for example sleep 1m, I have to wait till it's finished. But I want to have multiple childs in the background (and invalid commands shouldn't be executed).